# How to open an app on Droid via Python - SL4A Method?

Tags: android, python, automation, microsoft-edge, sl4a

I just recently decided to break into the mobile automation game, and stumbled upon SL4A via Python for Droid. I'm looking for a way to open an app on my Droid device via Python. I've heard that SL4A is a Python package that can hopefully do just that. Basically, I want to have a script that will be made into a clickable icon, whereby when pressed, opens Microsoft Edge and runs a few predetermined searches.

So initially, I want to keep it simple. I merely want to know how to open the Microsoft Edge app.

I've found a bit of code that may be of use:

```
import sl4a
droid=sl4a.Android()
droid.launch('com.imo.android.imoim')
```

Can I simply replace the 'com.imo.android.imoim' section of the following code with the location for Microsoft Edge's app? All I want, to start, is to open the app. Any and all advice would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also have worked with SL4A using the app Qpython:
Basically you can do this:

```
import sl4a
droid=sl4a.Android()
droid.startActivity("android.intent.action.MAIN", None, None, None, False,"com.microsoft.emmx", "com.microsoft.ruby.Main")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the repsonse. Going to  give this a go soon